# UINavigationController not executing completionBlocks when presenting ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, presentmodalviewcontroller

This one is tricky. I have a subclass of UINavigationController that overrides pop/push and present/dismiss methods. Here I customise the behaviour to set the correct size if the UINavigationController subclass is contained in a popover. Nothing too fancy, but I do it this way to don't write subclasses of all my ViewControllers and use Autolayout.

However, the completion blocks of the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` are not being executed. And this is the weird part: the exact same code on iPhone works correctly, but on iPad is not executing the blocks. Here is a code sample.

```
@interface SBNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

@implementation SBNavigationController

- (void) presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    if ([viewControllerToPresent isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) viewControllerToPresent;
        [nav.topViewController setContentSizeForViewInPopover:kFullSizePopover];

    } else
    {
        [viewControllerToPresent setContentSizeForViewInPopover:kFullSizePopover];
    }

    viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}

- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion ;
{
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
@end
```

And the code using it is this:

```
@implementation SBInviteFBContactViewController

...

- (void) createInviteByMailViewController
{
    SBInviteMailViewController *mailInvite = [[SBInviteMailViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self userInfo:_userInfo];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mailInvite];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navController
                                            animated:YES
                                          completion:^{

                                              NSLog(@"presentViewController:");

                                          }];

}

#pragma mark SBInviteMailProtocol

- (void) invitedMailContacts:(NSArray *)contacts;
{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                  completion:^{
                                                      NSLog(@"animation Ended");
                                                      if (contacts) {
                                                          [self.delegate invitedMailContact:contacts];
                                                          [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                                      }
                                                  }];
}

...

@end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: mmm... the plot thickens... if I comment out the line `viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;` then the blocks are executed, but the modal is presented full screen rather than inside the popover. Still annoying

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a *huge* bug. Please report it to Apple (and I am about to do the same). I found my way here because I just discovered the same bug myself, and did a google search to see if anyone else was talking about it.

I've created a very small demonstration project, whose architecture is like this:

- ViewController - the main view controller

  Its view contains a button Tap Me.
- PopoverViewController - presented in popover

  When you tap Tap Me in the main ViewController, it creates a UIPopoverController with *this* vc, PopoverViewController, as its content view controller; its view, too, contains a button Tap Me.
- PopoverViewController2 - presented "modally" in same popover

  PopoverViewController2 has its `modalPresentationStyle` set to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` so it can appear inside the popover. When you tap Tap Me in the popover, PopoverViewController calls `presentViewController:...`.

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)doTapMe:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"about to present view controller");
    [self presentViewController:[PopoverViewController2 new] animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"in completion handler"); // never called!
    }];
    NSLog(@"did present view controller");
}
```

The log reads "about to present view controller" and "did present view controller", but "in completion handler" never appears, even though the "modal" view controller's view appears in the popover just fine.

(Moreover, changing to `animated:NO` not only doesn't fix it, it causes a visual glitch.)

Answer (score 0):

The `UIModalPrsentationCurrentContext` style is only available if you are compiling against iOS 3.2 or greater.  Can't imagine that is the issue though.

The docs for `UIModalPrsentationCurrentContext` also say:

> When presenting a view controller in a popover, this presentation style is supported only if the transition style is UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical. Attempting to use a different transition style triggers an exception. However, you may use other transition styles (except the partial curl transition) if the parent view controller is not in a popover.

This is a strange one.

Any chance you're running a different version of iOS on the iPhone and the iPad?

Comment: Nope... building with iOS 6 SDK and trying on iOS 6 on both devices. But please read my comment on the question, if you comment out the modalPresentationStyle it works as expected (but takes the whole screen, not just the popover as wanted)